# Solr-php-client issue

Tags: php, solr

I am trying to run a script which can access a solr index using solr-php-client. THe script stops inside the ping function of `Apache_Solr_Service` class.

Then I tried to do this:

```
echo file_get_contents('http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/ping');
```

and got nothing -- blank page. BUT string http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/ping works as it should throw browsers address bar.

Can anybody suggest something on this?

Additional information: apache 2.2.3, CentOS 5.5, php 5.1.6, Solr 1.4.1

Thanks

Comment: Do you have `allow_url_fopen` setting turned on from php.ini?

Comment: Apache/PHP and Solr are running on the same machine, right?

Comment: No errors at all:

<?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  echo file_get_contents("http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/admin/ping");

Comment: Stop! ini_set(xxx) allow to display message: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/index.php on line 4

Comment: Line 4: echo file_get_contents("http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/admin/ping");

Answer (score 1):

Either, simply, just add a trailing forward slash after your url like this:

```
echo file_get_contents('http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/ping/');
```

Or just make sure you're not running in multicore mode. In which case you'd need to specify the name of your core before the admin like this

```
echo file_get_contents('http://localhost:8983/solr/CORE_NAME/admin/ping/');
```

First option should work for you though.

Also be aware where you host your code. It should be on that "localhost", otherwise make solr listed to a public IP and access that IP with php-solr-client.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Try</strike>

`echo file_get_contents('http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/admin/ping');`

Okay, try:

```
<?php

  $curl_handle=curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL,'http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/ping');
  curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
  $buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
  curl_close($curl_handle);

  echo $buffer;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
semanage port -a -t http_port_t -p tcp 8983
```

Check this: http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux -- see 5.4. Allowing Access to a Port section

Thanks for your help!